# Unsure what this Eigenvalue means?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In this Eigenvalue/vector question, the Eigenvalue v in the question is (-1,1,1)ᵀ. I'm not sure what to make of this, I don't understand if it's a list or something, or what the superscript T is. I haven't linked the full question, I just need to understand this first bit. Any help is appreciated.

[photo of the eigenvalue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqclP.png)

Comment: Probably is a typo, it is meant to be eigenvector

Comment: Regarding the notation: $(-1, 1, 1)^T$ is the transpose of the row vector $(-1, 1, 1)$, which is the column vector $\displaystyle\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. The "question" has at least two problems: as @DhanviSreenivasan noted, $\mathbf{v}$ is probably meant to be an eigenvector, not an eigenvalue. Maybe more importantly, there's no actual question.